# sudo does not find tlmgr

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, linux

I have just installed texlive 2014 on a machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS at work. When I enter `tlmgr update --self` to the terminal for example, it returns the following:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
```

as expected.

When I use sudo, however, the answer is as follows:

```
sudo: tlmgr: command not found
```

Interestingly enough though, when I enter `sudo su`, the command is well known.
Moreover, when I enter `sudo -i` and then `echo $PATH`, the output is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux
```

As well as the output for `echo $PATH` when entered without `sudo -i`:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux
```

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: It seems the super user (root) doesn't have the installation directory of `tlmgr` in its `PATH`. If the OS  should be able to find `tlmgr` for root, then use `PATH=${PATH}:<installation directory of tlmgr>`. (You may have to add `export PATH` too.) If I had to do this, I'd put the `PATH=...` statement in the root's login file, which I suspect is `.bashrc` in the root's home directory.

Comment: My advice is to place the path to TeX binaries at the head of `PATH` and not at the tail. Usually I make an alias or shell function `sutlmgr` that does `sudo /path/to/tlmgr` explicitly.

Comment: the super user does indeed not have the installation directory, when I enter `sudo su` and then `echo $PATH` the directory is not printed. I added the line `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` to the `/root/.bashrc` file, but `sudo` will still not find the command. `sudo su` still works. If possible, I would like to change the root's  `PATH` variable instead of writing an alias or shell function, though...

Comment: I usually make a pseudo sudo called `psudo`: in `.bashrc` or a file sourced by it, I use: `alias psudo='sudo env PATH="$PATH"' # usage: psudo tlmgr <whatever>`.  (This assumes your paths are set up normally according to the installation directions.

Comment: Just an other way that works for me: `sudo -i tlmgr update --all`.

Comment: See also https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/issues/13#issuecomment-54010889

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a more general UNIX sysadmin question, but you can use `visudo` to add

```
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

**Edit that path for your environment!**
See https://wiki.debian.org/sudo or https://www.google.com/search?&q=sudo+secure_path on the web, and the manual page for `sudoers(5)`.