# TeX Live permissions on OS X

Tags: texlive, installing, mactex, mac, distributions

So, after installing TeX Live 2015 (via the downloadable package) next to Homebrew, my directory-structure looks like this

```
drwxr-xr-x  24   ec admin   816 20 Jan   20:58 | /usr/local
drwxr-xr-x 176   ec admin  5984 20 Jan   21:46 + /usr/local/Cellar 
...
drwxr-xr-x  55   ec admin  1870 20 Jan   21:50 + /usr/local/share 
drwxr-xr-x   5 root wheel   170 20 Jan   21:32 + /usr/local/texlive 
drwxr-xr-x   7   ec admin   238 13 Oct   19:52 + /usr/local/var
```

(Something look a little out-of-place? `:P`)

```
> tlmgr install latex latex-bin latexconfig latex-fonts
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2015/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local     admin.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

So, I'd *really* rather not run commands as root, thanks.

Was there a correct way to install TeX Live that *doesn't* require subsequent `sudo` to run commands? `/=` And in either case, is it safe to recursively-`chown` the entire `/usr/local/texlive` tree, to repair this?

(I [don't seem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203874/sudo-does-not-find-tlmgr) to be [the first one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288545/installing-with-tlmgr-without-sudo-to-texmf) to have these problems ...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MacTeX package will always install TeX Live as root, as authorization is ordinarily required in order to write to `/usr/local`. Even if you change ownership or permissions, Apple's Installer is more of a glorified `tar` than anything. If you don't like that, you can install it using the shell script or from within TeX Live Utility.

As maintainer of TeX Live Utility, I *recommend* that you recursively `chown` the the tree to your user on a (primarily) single-user system, in order to avoid running my code and `tlmgr` with root privileges. It's safe to do this, but I wouldn't call it a "repair", since you've changed permissions on a directory that's owned by root in a clean install.

Comment: Keeping user and group as root, `chmod -R 755` on your TeX Live directory should work well.

Comment: I've tried both chown and chmod recursively, and Tex Live still requires password to update packages.  Any ideas?

Comment: @domoarigato I don't recommend chmod, as you're likely to break programs and scripts. To what user did you assign ownership? Do you mean "TeX Live Utility" still requires password? The Log Window in TLU will tell you if it's doing a recursive permissions check, but I don't recall if it tells you what file that it fails on. You can find that yourself easily enough.

Comment: Ok, so you were right - chmod was a bad idea.  I ended up deciding to reinstall mactex to fix the permissions.  But now TLU doesn't recognize that packages I had previously installed, even though they are still in the directory.  I am assuming there is some kind of database that got destroyed, and am hoping you can tell me a way to rebuild it.  At the moment, typesetting still works, but I guess I will not be receiving updates on those packages.

Comment: @domoarigato I'm not sure exactly what you did; TLU is just a front end for tlmgr, which maintains its own database of packages installed. If you manually modify /usr/local/texlive/2021, then it's not going to know what you've done. I assume any such modifications would have been wiped out by reinstalling MacTeX, though.

Comment: First I `chown -R` then I `chmod -R 755` as in the comment.  I observed that the Log Window reported that root was still required, and yes, it did point to the file that failed, which was a script.  Because of this, I decided to reinstall mactex (basic).  Afterwards, I re-chown'd the directory.  After that, TLU still doesn't seem to understand that certain packages that are installed are actually installed.  I can still build using them - ie. pdflatex and xelatex seem to work normally, but if I go into TLU, and search for the package, it appears to be not installed.

Comment: @domoarigato OK, I wondered if you were actually using basictex instead of mactex. If you didn't wipe out the previous install manually, either in Finder or Terminal, the Apple Installer left those additional packages in place, but tlmgr doesn't know about them in its database. You can either remove the directory and reinstall basictex, or just (re)install those additional packages manually in TLU from the Packages tab.

Comment: in the end I had to reinstall them